# Can I fix hardened bumps under inside corner tape without removing the tape and starting over?

Tags: drywall

I installed new inside corner tape in a bathroom. After all attempts to make it smooth, there are several 4 to 5 inch long bumps of hardened compound under the tape. Yes, I mudded the outside of the tape and wet and dry sanded. the compound has thoroughly dried. Is there any way I can get these bumps out without actually tearing out the job and starting over?

Comment: Pictures might help. If they aren't in the seam, you can always just sand right through the tape.

Comment: Thanks. In the end, I used a wet rag and reworked the areas. It seems I was able to soften the compound ridges and work them flatter. A skim coat tomorrow and it will have to do.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to tear out the tape, just sand or scrape through the high spots and skim it. The only problem with doing that is if you have a substantial length missing at the actual joint, say over an inch.